# Как в .htaccess ограничить доступ к виртуальному пути для всех IP кроме одного?

Tags: .htaccess, ssh

Для того что бы ограничить доступ к каталогу для всех IP кроме одного, нужно положить в него .htaccess со следующим содержанием:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 1.1.1.1
```

Можно в virtual hosts сделать это таким образом

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/mysite/my_folder">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 1.1.1.1
</Directory>
```

Но как решить эту задачу, если каталога my_folder нет и это виртуальный путь?

Ниже содержание .htaccess каталога mysite

/var/www/html/mysite/.htaccess :

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^favicon.ico$ - [F,L]
# если директория или файл существуют, использовать их напрямую
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# иначе отправлять запрос на файл index.php
#RewriteRule . index.php <-- было
RewriteRule ^([^/].*)$ /index.php/$1 [L] # <-- стало
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

содержимое файла `.htaccess` может влиять только на поведение соответствующим образом сконфигурированного *http*-сервера (и далеко не всякая реализация такого сервера это умеет «из коробки»), подключение к которому *http*-клиентов осуществляется по протоколу [*http*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP).

вы же с помощью программы `scp` (*ssh*-клиента) подключились к *openssh*-серверу по протоколу [*ssh*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH).

так что ничего удивительно (или странного, или ошибочного) в том, что вам удалось скопировать файл, нет: так и должно было произойти — ни наличие, ни отсутствие, ни содержимое файла `.htaccess`, находящегося где-либо в пределах земной орбиты, не могло никаким образом повлиять на **данную** ситуацию.

Comment: Э... я не вижу в вопросе ни одного упоминания scp и копирования файла. И тем более не могу понять, что означает "виртуальный путь" применительно к протоколу ssh...

Comment: Тем удивительнее видеть зеленую галочку слева от ответа. Что вообще происходит?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, автор внёс правку в вопрос, из-за чего суть несколько поменялась.

Comment: Хм, то есть автор сначала отметил ответ как решение, а потом привел вопрос у тому виду, при котором ответ стал глупым?.. Ну ок :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, если считаете нужным, откатите последнюю правку вопроса. я получаюсь лицом заинтересованным, потому не имею морального права так сделать.

Comment: У меня было задание, написать определенные правила для каталога в .htaccess. А так как я не знал как это проверить, то проверял, подключаясь по ssh и не мог понять почему .htaccess не работает. После ответа alexander barakin'a мне стало ясно что я делаю не так. А далее вопрос изменился совсем немного, я убрал упоминание про ssh и добавил "виртуальные пути" и .htaccess с +FollowSymLinks. Я не видел смысла создавать другую тему, которая будет почти полностью дублировать предыдущую

Comment: Я думаю, цель этого сайта помогать людям решать задачи, а не коллекционировать "умные" ответы. Если модераторы посчитают что это не так, могу перенести этот вопрос в новую тему.

Answer (score 0):

Для того что бы в настройках апача прописать правила для виртуальных путей, нужно использовать `<Location>` вместо `<Directory>`. Таким образом ответ на текущую версию вопроса будет такой:

```
<Location /my_folder/>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 1.1.1.1
</Location>
```